# Как отследить окончание сессии по времени в Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, сессия

Есть необходимость отслеживать действия пользователей, в том числе вход и выход из системы. Отследить выход по нажатию на клавишу просто, а вот как его отследить, если сессия истекла по времени? Использую Laravel 7.7.1

Comment: а зачем? истекание сессии это же не действие пользователя

Comment: @ВадимАлександру как бы да, но он же выходит из системы с истеканием сессии

Comment: Так храните время последней его активности, и по истечению определенного к-ства времени считайте что он вышел из системы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Идея такая: отслеживать устаревшие сессии и записывать в журнал их данные (текущая дата, пользователь) - это то что вам нужно.

В механизме сессий PHP есть обработчик, который удаляет старые сессии - сборщик мусора. Он работает так: при старте сессии (зашел новый посетитель) PHP случайным образом (вероятность настраивается) запускает сборщик мусорных сессий. Если в качестве хранилища используется файловая система, то PHP просто ищет устаревшие файлы и удаляет их, это зашито в его коде и работает по-умолчанию. [Вот исходный код](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/session/session.c), функция `static zend_long php_session_gc`

Но можно реализовать свой сборщик мусора, для этого нужно расширить класс `SessionHandler` и в нем реализовать метод [SessionHandler::gc()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/sessionhandler.gc.php), а затем установить обработчик сессий через `session_set_save_handler()`.

А в Laravel даже сделали обертку в виде [\SessionHandlerInterface::gc()](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/session#adding-custom-session-drivers).

Вот что нужно сделать для отслеживания истекающих сессий.

1. [Сконфигурировать хранение сессий в базе данных](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/session#configuration)
2. [Создать таблицу БД](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/session#driver-prerequisites)
3. Написать свою реализацию сборщика мусора, отнаследовавшись от `\Illuminate\Session\DatabaseSessionHandler` и зарегистрировать его [средствами Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/session#registering-the-driver)
4. Так как очистка мусора инициируется стартом новой сессии (заходом посетителя на сайт), а посетителей может и не быть, можно подтюнить:

> Поэтому рекомендуется выполнять сборку мусора на рабочих системах периодически, например, использовать задачи cron в UNIX-подобных системах. При этом убедитесь, что отключили сборку мусора на основе вероятности, установив session.gc_probability в 0

https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.session-gc.php

### Своя реализация сборщика мусора

Все что нам нужно, это отнаследовать свой обработчик от `\Illuminate\Session\DatabaseSessionHandler` и переписать в нем метод `gc`.

Так сделано в родительском классе:

```
public function gc($lifetime)
{
  $this->getQuery()->where('last_activity', '<=', $this->currentTime() - $lifetime)->delete();
}
```

Так нужно сделать в дочернем:

```
public function gc($lifetime)
{
  /**
   * тут пишем запрос, который из таблицы sessions берет user_id и другую
   * информацию и записывает в журнал
   */

  // вызываем родительский метод очистки мусора
  parent::gc($lifetime);
}
```

Comment: А можно ли просто править существующий обработчик? Т.е. перед удалением сессии в существующем обработчике впихнуть запись в базу, что пользователь вышел из системы, а после удаления сессии перебрасывать пользователя на домашнюю страницу.

Comment: И если я храню сессию в файле, можно ли провернуть тоже самое?

Comment: @GrizzlyK, по первому комменту не понял вас. По второму - можно, просто сложнее. По базе можно запросом вытащить просрочку, а вторым - удалить. А в варианте с файлами - нужно будет взять INI параметр "директория хранения сессий", найти просрочку по атрибуту "последняя дата обновления файла" (кажется так, но я сам точно не знаю), прочитать файл, записать из него информацию в журнал, затем удалить файл. Видите, это сложнее.

Comment: `Т.е. перед удалением сессии в существующем обработчике впихнуть запись в базу`. Если вы про нативный обработчик PHP, то есть тот, что используется "из коробки", то - нет. Он реализован на C++.